# Binding select element to array in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular

I wanted to bind a select element values to array RelatedComponentIDs:

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="RelatedComponentIDs">
        <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
        <option [ngValue]="type.Value" *ngFor="let type of allComponents">{{ type.Name }}</option>
      </select> 

this.form= this.formBuilder.group({
 RelatedComponentIDs: [[]],
});
```

When I am selecting any value in select, it is mapping to RelatedComponentIDs but as a string not as a array.
I wanted it to return to array.
Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: The field formControlName is a string, what do you want to achieve? Do you want several `select` elementS?

Comment: The question isn't clear at all. You're iterating through allComponents creating select options, and this is pretty common. Why you have to "return to array"?

Comment: Because I wanted to map relatedComponentIds property to array property of model which is been sent to api for furtehr processing.

Comment: Also same property is also used with select element for multiple selection.

Comment: whatever value user is selecting, I want to convert the string into array of strings

Comment: Into an array of which strings? What exactly you wish to achieve is very unclear here.

Comment: @PrateekAgrawal you can use `Array.from(this.form.get('RelatedComponentIDs').value)` before sending it to API. Any formcontrol except formArray will be saved in string only as per reactive form design. You can modify it like above before sending it to API. You can also use a hidden field which will store the selected dropdown value in Array format and use it before sending to API.